# How do I convert a text date in excel from dd.mm.yy to dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I convert a text date in excel from dd.mm.yy to dd/mm/yyyy? and have the new dd/mm/yyyy cell an actual date cell?

Comment: Did you try this? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-dates-stored-as-text-to-dates-8df7663e-98e6-4295-96e4-32a67ec0a680

Comment: Hi Hennes,

Unfortunately, there are no errors and when I try to convert the date into serial numbers using the formula there are only 0's and 1's as values. But thanks for the suggestion, much appreciated!

Comment: I ended up doing a LEFT, MID, and RIGHT to separate out the numbers followed by a CONCATENATE(number;"/";number;"/20;number) to get it from dd.mm.yy to dd/mm/yyyy

Then I used this formula to convert that output into an actual date type cell

=IF(ISNUMBER(H10);H10;DATEVALUE(H10))

Still wondering if there was an easier way?

Comment: Please post some sample data, without that we can only guess how it looks like. Also please don't give additional information in comments, but edit it into your question.

Comment: Have you tried doing a find and replace, swapping the `.` for a `/`?  Excel should then automatically recognize these as dates.  Be aware that if your system settings have date in American style (mm/dd/yy) then it may not work automatically since it will misinterpret which part is a day vs month.

Answer (score 1):

- *Suppose in cell `A2` you have written a date like, `13.12.2017` and it's format is Text.*

So to convert into `dd/mm/yyyy`, you can use the following.

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(RIGHT(A2,4)&"/"&MID(A2,4,2)&"/"&(LEFT(A2,2))),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

You get `13/12/2017`.

- If `A2` has `13.12.20`, then you should have to use this formula.

`=LEFT(A2,2)&"/"&MID(A2,4,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A2,2)`

You get `13/12/20`.

Comment: Formulaically, couldn't you instead use `=TEXT(DATEVALUE("13/12/2017"),"dd/mm/yyyy")`?

Comment: Yes @Arctiic,, it should be a better choice ☺

Answer (score 0):

Use find and replace

Ctrl+F

select the replace tab

In the find what tab put .
In the Replace with put /

click Options>

Change the format on the find what to whatever the cells you are referencing are formatted as.

That should change the date cells to the excel date format, then you can change the format of those cells to dd/mm/yy format

Comment: I'm curious why this was voted down, I'm trying to be helpful. This solution works for what I understood the problem to be.  I thought what was needed was to take cells that had dates in them in an unrecognized format dd.mm.yy and change those cells to dd/mm/yy format in the least steps possible. Are my steps unclear or did I misunderstand the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
G
```

Original    12.16.2017
    (cell G1)

```
H
```

Output  12
Cell Contents   =VALUE(LEFT(LEFT(G1,5),2))

```
I
```

Output  16
Cell Contents   =VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(G1,5),2))

```
J
```

Output  2017
Cell Contents   =VALUE(RIGHT(G1,4))

```
K
```

Output  12/16/2017
Cell Contents   =DATE(J1,H1,I1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this forumula:

```
=TEXT(DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2)),"DD/MM/YYYY")
```

The sample as shown in the following picture:

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0):

**Brett**

There are many ways to change or convert data type in excel  some of them i m describing below

1. If **DATA TYPE of  cell is  DATE** then Change the format of cell or column

**According to refereed  from website ablebits.com following link**

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/11/change-date-format-excel/
Default date format in Excel

> **How to change date format in Excel**
>
> In Microsoft Excel, dates can be displayed in a variety of ways. When it comes to changing date format of a given cell or range of cells, the easiest way is to open the Format Cells dialog and choose one of the predefined formats.
>
> 1. Select the **dates whose format your want to change,** or empty cells where you want to insert dates.
> 2. Press **Ctrl+1** to open the **Format Cells dialog.** Alternatively, you can right click the selected cells and choose Format Cells… from the context menu.
> 3. In the **Format Cells window, switch to the Number tab, and select Date in the Category list**. Under Type, pick a desired date format. Once you do this, the Sample box will display the format preview with the first date in your selected data.

[image: Date formaating]

> 4. If you are happy for the preview, click the OK button to save the format change and close the window.
> 5. If the **date format is not changing** in your Excel sheet, most likely your **dates are formatted as text** and you have to convert them to the date format first in step 2.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHOe5PQgIEU

> When you work with dates in Excel, **the short and long date formats are retrieved from your Windows Regional settings.** These default formats are marked with an asterisk (*) in the Format Cell dialog window:

[image: Regional seetings]

or use formula

for **further options details**  and  formats changing see the **link** mentioned above of ablebits.com  and find more details

2. If data type is not text **Converting  text to date**

**if you want to keep data type only in text format then**

```
 =SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","/")
```

or

```
=TEXT(DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2)),"DD/MM/YYYY")
```

**if you want to  change data type to  date data type**

```
=DATE(LEFT((DATEVALUE(A2)),4),MID((DATEVALUE(A2)),5,2),RIGHT((DATEVALUE(A2)),2))
```

**then change  the the format of of date data type  of column cell as  told in step 1 as per option or change regional seetings**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FErqhZl1Vds

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDen5VrV0cA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1AKuWDWOrY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FErqhZl1Vds

there are many ways see how to convert for your **reference and sharing**  i am  sending  many links for you  to look and understand  many other  ways with photographs steps and  explanations in details in following links

https://excelchamps.com/blog/text-to-date/

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3784-excel-convert-dd-mm-yyyy-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy.html#a1

https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-text-to-date

https://www.excelfunctions.net/convert-text-to-date.html

> If any of answer link or solution helped or  work then do tell me which  worked for you in comments for my knowledge and research and if not  then feel free to further  clarifications and doubts and if  worked then  please dont forget to  vote or accept the answer